# MyExtended Toolkit DataGrid for Uwp DataGrid TextColumn Binding Crashing Issue

Tags: c#, wpf, xamarin.forms, uwp

I Created New Uwp Project 
I added MyToolkit Extended Dll

I added one datagrid control in design page

```
<Page
    x:Class="App1.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App1"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
   xmlns:MyControls="using:MyToolkit.Controls"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <MyControls:DataGrid Name="bala" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">

        </MyControls:DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Code behind i added

// The Blank Page item template is documented at https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=402352&clcid=0x409

```
namespace App1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        List<data> lst = new List<data>() { new data() { iD = "1", Name = "bala" }, new data() { iD = "1", Name = "bala" }, new data() { iD = "1", Name = "bala" } };
        MyToolkit.Controls.DataGridTextColumn column = new MyToolkit.Controls.DataGridTextColumn();
        column.Binding = new Binding() { ElementName="iD"};
        column.Header = "ID";
        bala.Columns.Add(column);
        MyToolkit.Controls.DataGridTextColumn column1 = new MyToolkit.Controls.DataGridTextColumn();
        column1.Binding = new Binding() { ElementName = "Name" };
        column1.Header = "Name";
        bala.Columns.Add(column1);
        bala.ItemsSource = lst;
        }
    }
    public class data
    {
        public string iD { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I facing Crashing issue.

But Design side i added columns it will work fine. Code side only i am facing issue.

```
 <MyControls:DataGrid.Columns>
            <MyControls:DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Binding="{Binding iD}"></MyControls:DataGridTextColumn>
            <MyControls:DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}"></MyControls:DataGridTextColumn>
        </MyControls:DataGrid.Columns>
```

I am getting Run time Exception : 
**At least one object must implement IComparable.'**

Comment: At a minimum you should know what exactly your exception is. Use your debugger.

Comment: @jstreet i AM getting At least one object must implement IComparable.' this exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use **Path** for binding

```
column.Binding = new Binding() { Path = new PropertyPath("iD") };                              
        column1.Binding = new Binding() { Path = new PropertyPath("Name") };
```

This will work fine.